Why do we need another level of [] when using character classes?
See SELECT statement example here.
I also wrote it on my own, but the statement
SELECT prod_name FROM products WHERE prod_name REGEXP '[:digit:]{4}'
also worked. Could someone explain why?
I noticed for character classes in mysql regex, they usually work with another '[]' outside of it.
Why do we need another level of square bracket?

You only need to add additional square-brackets when the character-class is being used inside another bracket-expression - if you didn't then MySQL wouldn't know if the first ] after the last [ would close the bracket-expression or not.

@Dai could you give me a simple example?

The manual implies that the character class syntax works only inside a bracket expression. But in fact, the implementation works either way.
mysql> select 'abc123' regexp '[:alpha:]' as result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+

But if you wanted to use multiple character classes, you'd need to group them somehow.
The following doesn't work because the {6} applies only to the immediately preceding entity.
mysql> select 'abc123' regexp '^[:digit:][:alpha:]{6}$' as result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+

The following doesn't work because it's order-sensitive. The following matches exactly one digit followed by exactly one alpha character, repeated six times.
mysql> select 'abc123' regexp '^([:digit:][:alpha:]){6}$' as result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+

The bracket syntax is not order-sensitive, and it matches either of the characters, not both. This pattern matches either digit or alpha character, in any order, six times.
mysql> select 'abc123' regexp '^[[:digit:][:alpha:]]{6}$' as result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+

Compare with how you would write this without the character class syntax:
mysql> select 'abc123' regexp '^[0-9a-z]{6}$' as result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+

It's still inside brackets, to support matching any of the characters in the range.

Thanks Bill. after understanding your given examples, I would say, [:certain class:] can be used singly without another square brackets outside if you dont wanna make a composite set with another classes/elements. its equivalent to a typical set, right?

That's correct.
